# Resful way to update a field as a side effect of the PATCH request

Tags: api, rest

We have a model (table), for example -

```
MyModel={
    id,
    foo,
    bar,
}
```

When a user wants to update `foo` or `bar`, they send a PATCH request with the required keys and values.
For example:

Let's say I have MyModel object, id - 1234, foo=2, bar=1
The user updates foo to be 3:

```
PATCH ...../MyModel/1234
{
    'foo': 3
}
```

The response would be

```
200
{
    'id': 1234
    'foo': 3,
    'bar': 1
}
```

Now, there is a new requirement that sometimes, when updating `foo`, we will also update `bar` in the backend.

So the question is - is it right to do it, in REST terms? And - is there a right way to do it, other than sending the updated values in the response?